# chain href actions on html

Tags: javascript, html

Noob here.

I would like to know how to chain two actions using href. So basically I have a javascript action and additionally I would like to make a link to an other page.

```
    <div Id="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" "/some/url/here">Home</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
</div>
```

The

```
<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" "{% url 'Home' %}">Home</a>
```

does not work. I tryed `<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);{% url 'Home' %}">Home</a>` as suggested on another link but it did not work.

First it would be good to know if it is possible and if it is, how to do it.

Comment: There's nothing specific to Django here - if you replace the `url` templatetag by a hardcoded url the problem is exactly the same and so is the solution, it's really only HTML/javascript stuff (tags edited).

Comment: This is a javascript question and has nothing to do with Django. Lookup how to handle `onclick` events using javascript.

Comment: Why dont you just add the href in the javascript?

Comment: It is related to Django since the idea is to then  pass the url through the request.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but i don't think you can have javascript behaviour and navigate to a link. Navigating to another page would mean that your code has be be executed while your page is refreshing. You could have a button or even the link that you have right now and add onclick behaviour through something like jquery. Have a look at the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) of click.

Edit: As other said you can also just use java script without jquery as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)